# Cookie not set in browser for cross-subdomain authentication using Spring and axios

Tags: spring, cookies, next.js, axios

I'm having an issue where a cookie is not being set in the browser, despite seeing the Set-Cookie header in the network response. I have a development environment with a frontend deployed on app.mysite.com and a backend on api.mysite.com. When a user logs in, a Set-Cookie header is returned with the response.

I create the cookie in Spring like this:

```
private String createRefreshTokenCookie(String refreshToken) {
    return ResponseCookie.from(REFRESH_TOKEN_COOKIE_KEY, refreshToken)
            .maxAge(refreshTokenExpirationMs / 1000)
            .domain(".mysite.com")
            .httpOnly(true)
            .sameSite("None")
            .secure(true)
            .path("/")
            .build().toString();
}
```

Although I can see the Set-Cookie header in the response and the cookie being returned in the cookie tab of the network request in Chrome, it is not being set in the Application > Cookies window.
[image]
[image]

Additionally, the cookie does not get sent with the axios request, even though I have set withCredentials to true.

Here's my CORS configuration class in Spring:

```
registry.addMapping("/api/v*/**")
        .allowedOrigins(webAppUrl)
        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
        .allowedHeaders("*")
        .exposedHeaders("Set-Cookie", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Access-Control-Max-Age", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Origin", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization")
        .allowCredentials(true);
```

What am I missing here? Why is the cookie not being set and sent with subsequent requests?

Comment: the problem is most likely within one of the flags: 

```.domain(".mysite.com").httpOnly(true).sameSite("None").secure(true)``` 

Try commenting those out, and then uncoment one by one to identify the problem